# NHibernate not deleting orphans on update

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class, which has a list of an abstract class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have mapped the Bars as such:

```
HasMany(f => f.Bars).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphans();
```

However when I update a `Foo` to remove a `Bar` it doesn't delete the orphan but it does set Bar's `Foo_id` column to `NULL`?

I read around and saw answers saying to inverse the `HasMany` so I tried:

```
HasMany(f => f.Bars)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphans();
```

But then when saving the `Bar` always had `NULL` as the `Foo_id`. This was also the case when I tried adding a `KeyColumn`:

```
HasMany(f => f.Bars)
    .Inverse()
    .KeyColumn("Foo_id")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphans();
```

Comment: show me the code you use to remove a Bar

Answer (score 0):

Using these mappings:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(f => f.Bars).Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphans();
    }
}
public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Foo);
    }
}
```

To remove, you need to disassociate the bar from the foo from both ways:

```
// get foo object
var foo = dao.GetFooByID(1);

var barToRemove = foo.Bars[0]; // find the first bar

// disassociate the objects to properly trigger cascade deletion
barToRemove.Foo = null;
foo.Bars.Remove(barToRemove);

dao.SaveFoo(foo);
```

On the other hand, to add, you need to associate the objects from both ways as well:

```
// get foo object
var foo = dao.GetFooByID(1);

var barToAdd = new Bar(); // new bar to add

// associate the objects to properly trigger cascade save
barToAdd.Foo = foo;
foo.Bars.Add(barToAdd);

dao.SaveFoo(foo);
```

Comment: This is what I was doing except `Bar` doesn't have a reference to `Foo`.

Comment: Refer to the relationship between Employee and Store in the example here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: How does a Bar know which Foo it belongs to then? Just the FooID? From experience, in order for the cascading to work properly you need to have the object reference from the child to the parent. I updated my answer to show more complete mappings.